# help needed with xpath and selenium

Tags: xpath, selenium

selenium IDE gave me following xpath for string on page called "System". However this string may appear somewhere other than this place in future.

```
//ul[@id='idCTree_sor_ul']/li/ul/li[23]/span
```

how can I rewrite above xpath by spcifying text()="System" in xpath , so in future if index of that string is moved would not impact on my xpath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//span[./text() = 'System']
```

Comment: Hi matthew , thanks for your quick reply. the xpath you provided producing following error:
[error] locator not found: //span[./text() = 'System'], error = Error: Element //span[./text() = 'System'] not found

Comment: sorry it was my error while evaluating the xpath. Xpath you provided worked fine ...thanks

Comment: @doneright: You can't upvote (yet). Please at least accept an answer that helped you.

Comment: Just be aware that using the // ancestor axis can be extremely slow if your XML input is large.  I understand your desire to have XPath that will work if the XML changes, but part of the design of XPath is that it is tied to the XML structure.